# Determine regional business days and weekend days of the week

Tags: windows, globalization

In some countries weekend days are Friday/Saturday.

How can a Windows application find out weekend days of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wellll...I don't know of a "One function" answer to this.  You're gonna need to know where they are somehow.  If it's a webapp, you can trace their IP and figure out what country they are from.  If it's a windows app, you're probably going to need to ask them (The clock only provides timezone information, and i can't figure out where else to grab a more fine-grained location from windows).

You can figure out what day it is with GetDayofWeek http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wzak8d0%28VS.80%29.aspx in MFC

DayofWeek if you hop to .Net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

You'll need a lookup table with countries/what days they consider weekends..you'll probably have to construct this, but you can get a list of countries from: http://www.iso.org/iso/english_country_names_and_code_elements

That list is ISO 3166.

It's updated and should be your "one-stop-shop" for the listing.  From there, you'll match "weekends" to the countries.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek might help in figuring out weekends/workweeks for countries.

Comment: yeah, it was helpful. I am just giving other people a chance before accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will provide whether or not it is considered the weekend, with an option for different cultures (where the weekend starts/ends on a different day):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the specified date is weekend in given culture
    /// is in. 
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsItWeekend(DateTime currentDay, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        bool isItWeekend = false;

        DayOfWeek firstDay = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        DayOfWeek currentDayInProvidedDatetime = currentDay.DayOfWeek;

        DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = firstDay + 4;

        if (currentDayInProvidedDatetime == lastDayOfWeek + 1 || currentDayInProvidedDatetime == lastDayOfWeek + 2)
            isItWeekend = true;

        return isItWeekend;         
    }
```

Comment: So will it really work if .FirstDayOfWeek == Friday? At first sight it looks like "% 7" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

ICU project might help. It is designed for software internalization and globalization. C/C++ and Java version are available.

[icu-project.org](http://icu-project.org)