# How can I determine what days are the weekend?

Tags: .net, datetime, weekend

Using the .NET CultureInfo, how can I determine if a DateTime is in the weekend? The weekend is Saturday/Sunday in most of the world, but it's Friday/Saturday in Israel and the Muslim countries.

Anyone got a program that handles this? The question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102839/determine-regional-business-days-and-weekend-days-of-the-week) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019098/finding-weekend-days-based-on-culture), but not answered. I'm hoping someone has a table or method to do this.

Comment: I wrote my own code and posted the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019098/finding-weekend-days-based-on-culture/19478887#19478887 (which asked before I did).

Answer (score 0):

The .Net CultureInfo does not have the information you desire. Your only choice at this point is to write your own implementation which requires compiling your own data.